# Finding symmetric probability distribution with some property

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can someone help me find a probability distribution symmetric about the origin with the property that $P(X \geq 3Y) \neq 1/2$? I can't come up with anything for some reason. I've tried several p.d.fs of my own as well as well-known pdfs. $N(0, \sigma^2)$  and $U(-1, 1)$ don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are taking $\{X,Y\}$ to be i.i.d. Let $X$ take the values $0,+1,-1$ with probabilities $\frac 1 2 , \frac  1  4$ and $\frac  1 4$ respectively. Then $P(X \geq 3Y)=\frac  5 8$.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Kavi Rama Murthy's answer, perhaps (based on what you tried) what you might find useful is the proof of the fact that of $X$ and $Y$ are iid and $P(X = 3Y) = 0)$ (such as those with densities), then the probability you are looking for is going to be 1/2.

That follows from $P(X \geq 3Y) = P(-X \geq 3(-Y)) = P(X \leq 3Y)$ where the first equality follows from the independence and the symmetry. Now. the result follows from the facts that $X > 3Y, X < 3Y$ and $X = 3Y$ partition the space, and $P(X \geq 3Y) = P(X > 3Y) + P(X = 3Y)$